# What are the methods for tokenizing strings in .Net?

Tags: c#, java, .net, migration

This must be a classic .NET question for anyone migrating from Java.

.NET does not seem to have a direct equivalent to java.io.StreamTokenizer, however the JLCA provides a SupportClass that attempts to implement it.  I believe the JLCA also provides a Tokenizer SupportClass that takes a String as the source, which I thought a StreamTokenizer would be derived from, but isn't.

<strike>What is the *preferred* way to Tokenize both a Stream and a String? or is there one?</strike> How are streams tokenized in .Net?  I'd like to have the flexibility that java.io.StreamTokenizer provides.  Any thoughts?

Comment: While the OP phrased the question using language indicative of the solicitation of opinion, the context seems clear that he wasn't looking for opinions so much as functional equivalencies to Java's tokenizing APIs.  The essence was "Java does it this way.  How do you do the same in .Net?"  This isn't a "What frameworks do you like?" question.  As such, it should be reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't anything in .NET that is completely equivalent to StreamTokenizer. For simple cases, you can use String.Split(), but for more advanced token parsing, you'll probably end up using [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I wasn't especially looking at all the various places this Tokenizer would be used from... and you're right.  Most are simple enough for String.Split to be used.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use System.String.Split if you need to split a string based on a collection
of specific characters.

Use System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx.Split to split based
on matching patterns.

Answer (score 1):

To tokenize a string, use `string.Split(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tokenizer in the Nextem library -- you can see an example here: http://trac.assembla.com/nextem/browser/trunk/Examples/Parsing.n

It's implemented as a Nemerle macro, but you can write this and then use it from C# easily.

Comment: You can also use Nemerle.Peg macro: https://code.google.com/p/nemerle/source/browse/nemerle/trunk/snippets/peg-parser/ . It can be downloaded here: https://code.google.com/p/nemerle

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, for very simple tokenizing have a look at System.String.Split().

More complex tokenizing can be achieved by System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem of finding a StreamTokenizer equivalent when porting tuProlog from Java to C#. We ended up writing what as far as I know is a straight conversion of StreamTokenizer which takes a TextReader as a "stream" for input purposes. You will find the code in the [download for tuProlog.NET 2.1](http://sf.net/projects/tuprolog/) (LGPL-licensed) so feel free to reuse and adapt it to your needs.